# What is the best way to configure Postfix to send mail only on a production server?

Tags: security, postfix, ubuntu-12.04

I'm digging the web around to find the best way to configure Postfix.

I don't want to install a full Postfix server, the only thing I want is to send mail with the PHP mail(). I know this can be tricky, spammer loves the misconfigured mail server. So, I am looking for the best way to do this.

The best documentation I found is the [Archlinux one](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Postfix).

But on several blogs I found some more tricky configuration like this

```
myhostname = foo.me
mydestination = localhost
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8

myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = sd-24300.com , localhost
mail_owner = postfix

smtpd_recipient_restrictions =reject_unknown_sender_domain,reject_non_fqdn_sender,reject_unknown_recipient_domain,reject_non_fqdn_recipient,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination,permit
smtpd_data_restrictions =reject_unauth_pipelining,permit
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
```

So my question is quite easy, what is the best way to do this? By best i mean the more secure one.

Ps: My server runs a Ubuntu 12.04 with LAMP

Comment: To configure postfix as send-only (except for local mail), see [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/122777/61015).

Answer (score 5):

Use [`nullmailer`](https://github.com/bruceg/nullmailer) instead of Postfix, it is a relay-only server made for this purpose.

It's available in the `universe` repo.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using ubuntu you can select from a couple predefined configs using the command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure postfix
```

It should have one that fits your description.

Comment: This is much too vague, and factually untrue: while you could cobble something together by starting with the `satellite` config, there is no dpkg option that gives you a nullmailer.