# Mail Server for a subdomain on a different Server?

Tags: centos, email, postfix, centos6, pop3

I'm currently assigned the administration of a server that is accessed through a subdomain of another (not administrating example.com but y.example.com), and assigned to implement a web application on it. To allow registration, the web app requires sending email, so I'm configuring the server's mail service (is that the correct way to do it?)

So I tried using [this guide](http://www.krizna.com/centos/setup-mail-server-in-centos-6/) to make sure it is implemented correctly. Unfortunately I wasn't sure what to write as hostname and domain. While I after using telnet it gave me correct output, I couldn't reach it using thunderbird. It suggested that hostname should be something like this

```
myhostname = mail.example.com
mydomain = example.com
```

but I guess that would only work if it actually was done on example.com? How do I handle this?

Answer (score 1):

Your main domain doesn't have to point to your mailserver. You just need to add an `A Record` to your domains. For example you have `example.com` which points to a server hosting the main website.

You need to go to your DNS administration panel and create an `A Record` (e.g. mail ==> IP_ADDRESS) which directly points to your MailServer's IP address.

After that an `MX Record` must be set which will be equal to e.g. `mail.example.com`.

So after all of this your FQDN for your MailServer will be `mail.example.com`.

Please remember you have to update postfix's `main.cf` file (`mydestination`) and add every domain which your server will be responsible for, otherwise emails will be rejected.

Answer (score 1):

> To allow registration, the **web app requires sending email**, so I'm configuring the server's mail service (is that the correct way to do it?)

No, you don't have to set up full blown mail server just for app who required to send email. Just use [outgoing email service](https://serverfault.com/a/122802/218590) like [ssmtp](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ssmtp).